# How to aggregate data in mongoDB based on user input?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregate

I would like to use aggregate framework in mongoDB to query database based on user input. I created an app where after every letter which is typed, **fetch** retrieves all matching data. The more letters are typed the narrowerer the output.

### Example

User enters letter **G**, output is 10 JSON records.
User enters **Goodwill**, output is 1 (only one record matches word 'goodwill')

### Problem

I have to search for each typed **letter** or **number** in all of my JSON key value pairs. If user types anything I have to search **header**, **headerNum**, **content**, **contentNum**, **details**.

Currently, I solved this problem, but it is kind of a workaround. I'm using **RegExp** in mongoDB **find()** method to meet expected conditions. Then I'm using **map()** to filter all the results which are matching user's search.

### JSON

```
        "header": "Intangible assets",
        "headerNum": "10",
        "meta": [
            {
                "meta_id": "1",
                "header": "Intangible assets",
                "headerNum": "10",
                "content": "Random content and goodwill",
                "contentNum": "1080",
                "details": "Some random text with the word goodwill",
                "tags": ["goodwill"]
            }
        ]
    }
```

### Conditions

```
const search = req.query.term.toLowerCase();
const regExp = new RegExp(".*" + search + ".*", "gi");

    let conditions = [{
            "meta.header": regExp
        },
        {
            "meta.tags": regExp
        },
        {
            "meta.content": regExp
        },
        {
            "meta.details": regExp
        }
    ];

    if (typeof parseInt(search) === 'number') {
        conditions.push({"meta.headerNum": regExp}, {"meta.contentNum": regExp});
    }
```

### Creating query with find and map

```
db.getDB()
        .collection(collection)
        .find({
            $or: conditions
        })
        .map(function(record) {
            if (record.header.includes(search) || record.headerNum.includes(search)) {
                return record;
            }

            record.meta = record.meta.filter(function(meta) {
                return meta.tags.find(function(tag) {
                    return tag.toLowerCase().includes(search)
                }) || meta.content.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
                meta.details.toLowerCase().includes(search) || meta.contentNum.toLowerCase().includes(search)
            });
            return record;
        })
        .sort({headerNum: 1})
        .toArray((err, docs) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.json(docs.filter(function(record) { 
                    return record.meta.length;
                }));
            };
        });
```

I would like to replace find and map with aggregate. I was trying to do that with **unwind** but with no satisfactory result. Thanks in advance!